# File tree structure for Matlab Runtime(s)?

Tags: matlab, path, runtime

I'm following the info page for [installing the Matlab Runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/install-the-matlab-runtime.html).  There are 3 possible platforms: Windows, Linux, and macOS.

There are also a number of possible situations in which to install the Runtime.

1. Generic installation
2. Installation without administrator rights
3. Multiple Runtime versions on a single machine
4. Installation on a machine which already has Matlab

For #1, the user chooses a path, but no examples are given of what might be sensible.

For #2, the path is: *mcr_root* \ runtime \ *arch*.  My *arch* is Win64.

For #3, the path is not described.

For #4, the paths are:

- Windows: *mcr_root* \ *ver* \ runtime \ win64
- Linux: *mcr_root* / runtime / *arch*
- macOS: *mcr_root* / runtime

It seems to me that there is a lot of inconsistency in the path convention.  Does proper operation depend on adherence to a strict convention (which must be divined somwhow from the above information), or is it arbitrary?

Comment: For a machine that already has MATLAB, you don't need to install the runtime at all. The runtime is meant for people that don't have a MATLAB license. Other than that, you don't need to know the path at all. The user just runs your executable, the runtime will be found by it and used without you knowing where it is installed.

Comment: By the way, the user chooses `mcr_root` at install time, the rest is decided on by the installer. It is different on each platform because each platform has different conventions. The user can choose whatever directory for `mcr_root` that is convenient to them, it's irrelevant where it is.

Comment: Thanks, Cris. I'm not installing the Runtime to enable execution of the solution for myself, but to ensure that entire process of (say) wrapping a Matlab function as a Java package will work once it's shipped elsewhere. I'm not there yet, but that's the ultimate aim. Your comments indicate to me that, because the path components that come after `mcr_root` are arbitrary, the actual path will need to be supplied when it comes time to execute the solution.  Would you be able to post an answer?  Thanks.

Comment: No, the paths are not arbitrary, they are platform-dependent. I also said that you don't need to worry about these paths. When you create an executable (or library or whatever) with the MATLAB Compiler, and distribute that to a different machine, and the appropriate runtime is installed on that machine, then your executable will run. You don't need to know what the paths inside the runtime installation are.

Comment: Note also that your executable (or library or whatever) can run only on one specific platform. You need to build it three times if you want to distribute it for all three platforms. (Or at least this is how it used to work when I used the Compiler, it might have changed in the meantime.)

Comment: Would it be right to say that even though the `mcr_root` is chosen by the user, the entire structure under that folder is not?  Assuming that the answer is yes, I'm still stumped by the fact that item #2 in the question doesn't have a `ver` component in the path while item #4 does. And further still, does it mean that at the destination, the location of `mcr_root` needs to be provided somehow before the executable will run?  That is, assuming that the Runtime isn't packaged with the compilation.

Comment: That might be a misunderstanding on your part or an error in the documentation. I recommend that  you ask your MATLAB representative to clarify this point. In any case, when you run the installer, it asks you where to install the runtime. The directory you choose here will be `mcr_root`. You don't have any influence on the rest, the installer does this for you. The directory structure created by the installer is fixed for a given platform.

Comment: The runtime will be found by the executable, wherever it is installed. This is accomplished by appropriate environment variables (or registry setting in Windows). You really don't need to worry about any of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my synthesis of the information that Cris kindly provided (please feel free to clarify/correct).

If the Runtime isn't packaged together with the compiled code (a likely scenario, given the size of the Runtime), then it must be installed independently at the destination machine.  In this process, the user chooses the root folder for Runtime installation, i.e., `mcr_root`.  The tree structure therein is determined by TMW, and depends on the platform and version.  This is not something that needs to be determined by the person doing the compiling or the user of the compilation.  When the executable is run, it will know where the Runtime is because the Runtime installation process causes the location to be encoded in the Windows registry or *nix environmental variables.

You might still need to recognize the organization scheme.  As indicated in the webpage cited in the question, there may be cases where you have to ensure the proper ordering of relevant directories in the system path.